# Apple developer Account renewal - all devices to be reset

Tags: ios

During account renewal apple asked for device reset but unknowingly we have a selected all the devices. Now all the devices are added to the newly renewed account. I want all the old devices to be deleted.I didn't add any new devices yet. Is it possible?. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***No***. You can't do it.

> Important Note: At the start of your membership year, make sure to
>   remove all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding
>   any new devices.

For more [info](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html) :

Comment: I didn't add any devices yet.

Comment: I didn't add any new devices, didn't create new provisions and certificates.

Comment: @BlueBerry I'd suggest contacting Apple tech support and requesting them to delete the devices in your dev a/c. I have heard in some cases they considered the request and deleted the list of devices. You can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will contact apple support

Comment: @BlueBerry: Did you get any proper help from apple support?, For me, On Device reset date(Account Renewal day), it was Sunday. Thats why i haven't even opened the developer account, on next day, it is not giving me any option to remove older devices

Comment: @Mehul Thakkar - Did you get any response on this from apple support?

Comment: @ravisendhav: Actually.. when i logged out and logged in again.. at that time.. and moving to devices page.. it showed me "warning" like line at top saying update device list.. so that it worked for me